# Redirect all traffic to one sub-directory with httpd.conf

Tags: apache, redirect, httpd.conf

I have a `httpd.conf` file with many domains configured on my server. I need to redirect an old directory on just one website to a new directory.

Basically, when a user accesses any page in the dir `domain.com.au/store` , I want them to be redirected to `domain.com.au/shop`.

I don't want the redirect to include the old webpath, so any old URL needs to redirect only to the `domain.com.au/shop` page, not to `/shop/old_webpath`.

I've tried many redirect entries from around the web, none seem to work correctly, as they all redirect to `/shop/old_webpath`, not just `/shop`.

Can any apache minds help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^store/(.*)$ \/shop
</IfModule>
```

Update for virtual host in apache configuration for `domain.com.au`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # ...
    <Directory "[your_path]">
        # ...
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com\.au$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^store/(.*)$ \/shop
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to add this to httpd.conf and limit it only to the specific URL? Otherwise /store on any website will redirect to /shop on any website

Comment: Thank you so much, but even though I have the rewrite mod enabled, including `RewriteBase /` causes Apache restart to fail and the entries have no effect.

Comment: delete line with `RewriteBase` and restart Apache, if rules are in `vhost` configuration, must work only for this `vhost`.

Comment: Still just having no luck, by my virtual host is configured like so: 

`<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias domain1.com domain2.com domain3.com.au domain4.com.au domain5.com
ServerName domain.com`

Comment: Is something as simple as this possible?:

`Redirect permanent http://domain.com.au/store http://domain.com.au/shop`